# R Base Plot suppress axis line but show ticks

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I am having the following issue with the axis() function.

```
 axis(1,
       at=1:length(stringi::stri_rand_strings(21, 15)),
       labels=stringi::stri_rand_strings(21, 15),
       tick=1,
       lwd=1,
       mgp = c(0,1,0),
       col = title_colour,
       col.ticks = title_colour
       ,lty = "solid",
       cex.axis = 1,las=2,cex=0.75)
```

[image]

But whatI really need are the tickmarks without the continuous x'x line connecting the ticks:

[image]

How do I accomplish this using axis()??

Comment: use `lwd` _and_ `lwd.ticks`: `axis(1, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)`

Comment: That's the one I used. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `col` to `NA` but `col.ticks` to a value:

```
plot(1, type = 'n', axes = FALSE)
axis(1, c(0.75, 1, 1.25), col = NA, col.ticks = 1)
```

[image]

(Note my *reproducible* and *minimal* example, try to include that in your question!)