# In plot() for R, box() overlaps with axis lines in R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

When I use box() with plot() and add some axes, the line where the tick marks are attached to the axes overlays with the box lines so you see a thickened line at the axis. How do you remove this overlap?

See code and diagram for more:

```
x <- seq(-pi,pi,0.1)
plot(x, sin(x), axes=FALSE)
axis(side=1, at=seq(-2, 1, by = 1))
axis(side=2, at=seq(-0.5, 0.5, by = 0.3))
box()
```

So you can see on the x and y axis there appears to be a thicker "double" line in the center, which just looks messy.

[image]

Note: I know one way to eliminate this problem is by making `axes=TRUE`, but I have a lot of specifications to add so I need to make `axes=FALSE` and then add `axis()` as a separate function.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Which device are you using? Is it the RStudio graphics device? The lines are supposed to overlap - it's just that you shouldn't see the overlap because the lines are the same width and color. If resetting your device by doing `dev.off()` then running your code again doesn't help,  It looks as though if you add `lwd = 0.5` to your `axis` calls (or maybe `lwd = 2` to your `box` call), the apparent overlap will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `col` and `col.ticks` to get the desired output. Here is the code:

```
x <- seq(-pi,pi,0.1)
plot(x, sin(x), axes=FALSE)
axis(side=1, at=seq(-2, 1, by = 1),  col = NA, col.ticks = 1)
axis(side=2, at=seq(-0.5, 0.5, by = 0.3), col = NA, col.ticks = 1)
box()
```

Now the plot doesn't have those double lines [image: Rplot]

Same issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932941/r-base-plot-suppress-axis-line-but-show-ticks). Thanks